# Avoiding entering value of ether in smart contract in Remix Injected Web 3 environment

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I'm writing a smart contract so that a metamask wallet can send a certain value of eth to the smart contract. However, every time I tested the smart contract, I have to manually enter an integer. Is there any way I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nope, sending eth it's not a part of tx data, but it is inside tx details, if you run that function directly on IDE REMIX, or etherscan, you have to insert it manually

anyway if you are planning to make an interface for your contract using web3js, you can manually add tx details like that before sending the tx:

```
const transaction = {
 'to': '0x31B98D14007bDEe637298086988A0bBd31184523', //contract address 
 'value': 1, //1 eth
 'gas': 30000,
 'maxFeePerGas': 1000000108,
 'nonce': nonce,
};
```

so the user doesn't need to write it manually